# swapExactTokensForTokens "this should not happen"

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation

I can't find any answer about this :
I'm calling swapExactTokensForTokens and get this message : "this should not happen"

I'm using NodeJs & ethers.utils.

```
const Provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider('0xXXXXXX');

const Wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic("word1 word2 ...");

const Account = Wallet.connect(Provider);

const Factory = new ethers.Contract('0xYYYYYYY', ['event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint)'], Account);
const Router = new ethers.Contract('0xZZZZZZ',
                                   ['function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
                                   'function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)'],
                                   Account);

let tokenIn = Addresses.WBnb;

let tokenOut = Data.WantedToken;

const amountInF = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.1', 'ether');

const amountsF = await Router.getAmountsOut(amountInF, [tokenIn, tokenOut]);

const amountOutMinF = amountsF[1].sub(amountsF[1].mul('10').div('100'));

const gasPriceF = ethers.utils.parseUnits(Data.GasPrice, "gwei");

const txApprove = await CBnb.approve(Router.address, amountInF, {gasPrice: gasPriceF, gasLimit: Data.GasLimit});
const receiptApprove = await txApprove.wait();
```

I'm pretty sure the infos are ok and in the right unit.
I'm not on Uniswap but on BSC.
Does someone has some thoughts about this?

Comment: You must add much more info to your question.

Comment: I think you should search your sources (or the sources of the tokens you are swapping) for "this should not happen" string, because I am pretty sure Uniswap v2 doesn't have such weird error message

Comment: Question is updated.

Comment: @user78481 like Nulik said, this is clearly something with one token you are swapping with. swapping uses the token methods internally, so if you have any error that doesn't start with Uniswap at first it is probably not part of the swapping contract.

Comment: For the approve function, I use WBNB, and for swapping function WBNB in and BUSD out.
I have enough WBNB, and enough BNB for tx.